# linq to entity,How does the where clause use ?: Expression

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

`TAB_XXX` and `TAB_XXX_details` are one-to-many relationships, I need to query the two tables, however, we need to be filtered `TAB_XXX_details`。

The code is as follows：

```
var qu = from c in db.TAB_XXX.Where(n => n.DELETE_MARK == false)
        let dets = c.TAB_XXX_DETAILS.Where(n => condition.SaleType.HasValue ? n.SALE_TYPE == (decimal)condition.SaleType : 1 == 1)
        select new
        {
            c,
            dets
        };
```

`Condition.SaleType` is `number?`, if the `condition.SaleType` is a valid number, such as 1, 2, 3 ... I want to filter the child record based on these numbers; when the `condition.SaleType` is `null`, I want to query `TAB_XXX` and all its child records;

How do I modify the where clause?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: _"Condition.SaleType is number?"_, what type is `number?`

Comment: @TimSchmelter `public decimal? SaleType { get; set; }`

Comment: @TimSchmelter `Condition` is a sort of query class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `1 == 1` is always `true`, your condition boils down to this:

```
let dets = c.TAB_XXX_DETAILS
    .Where(n => !condition.SaleType.HasValue || n.SALE_TYPE == condition.SaleType.Value)
```

Essentially, you want to return all rows when `condition.SaleType` does *not* have value; otherwise, you make a comparison to `condition.SaleType.Value`.